# Changing Coordinates by Translation

Tags: abstract-algebra, isometry

I'm studying isometries right now, and I'm kind of confused as to how a translation changes coordinates. My book uses the notation where $t_p(\vec{x})$ denotes a translation on $\vec{x}$ by $\vec{p}$; this all makes sense so far. However, I don't understand how the translation works in practice; does the translation move the origin to the point $(6,4)$, for example, so that $(6,4)$ is the new origin, and if so, how does that even work with the rule for change of coordinates $t_p(\vec{x}') = \vec{x}$, where $\vec{x}'$ is the new coordinate vector of our original vector $\vec{x}$? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Per the book, let $x$ and $y$ be vectors such that $y = m(x)$ for an isometry $m$. Our change in coordinates will be given by some isometry, let's denote it by $\eta$. Let the new coordinate vectors of $x$ and $y$ be $x'$ and $y'$. The new formula $m'$ is the one such that $m'(x') = y'$. We also have the formula $\eta(x') = x$ analogous to the change of basis formula $PX' = X$. To clarify, the book is Artin's Algebra.

Comment: Can you copy the rule for the change of coordinates into the question? That might help narrow down exactly what your book is saying.

Comment: @DavidK There you go :)

Comment: That was not quite what I was looking for, but someone who has a copy of Artin (and I think there may be several regulars who do) might be able to identify and clarify the passage in question now.

Comment: Translation is simply a *mapping* $t_p=x\mapsto x+p$, which is *not linear* (only *affine*), and so we usually don't even consider a 'change of coordinates' matrix for it. Nevertheless, we can easily say what happens to the coordinates when $t_p$ is applied.

Comment: @Berci Hmm, that makes sense, this might be a stupid comment but I'm guessing that the translation vector equals $-1$ times the vector $p$ in $t_p(x) = x$? Also, do you happen to have a copy of Artin?

Comment: I don't have. If it's $t_p(x)=x'$, then $x'=x+p$ (and consequently, $x=x'-p=t_{-p}(x')$).

Comment: @Berci Okay, of course, thanks for the clarification!